# Can't use 64 bit ie or tortoisesvn with smartcard, but can use 32 bit ie, svn, chrome, firefox, thunderbird

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, troubleshooting, smartcard

I have a Dell M6700 running windows 7 ultimate 64-bit.  I have gotten my smart card to work with chrome, firefox, thunderbird, ie 32-bit, collabnet svn client 32-bit.

When I use ie 64-bit, it never asks me for my smart card's pin, and then just errors out.
When I use svn 64-bit (collabnet or tortoisesvn), same thing happens.

I could use some pointers.

Comment: So obviously you need 64-bit drivers for the card ...

Comment: @RandolphWest - The reader already works so this isn't a driver problem.  It just doesn't work when ued against a 64-bit browser.  This is likely a problem with the fact you need a 64-bit plugin of collabnet that supports IEx64

Comment: I meant 64-bit plugin, not driver. You are correct.

Comment: would you mind clarifying on what you mean by plugin?  I'm woefully unfamiliar with drivers.  If it helps, I don't believe that I'm using collabnet via ie64 as a plugin, (or maybe it is doing that and no one's told me).  If I misunderstood your suggestion....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vendor of the middleware hadn't released 64bit drivers, which was not documented anywhere, hence the mystery.